# Node.JS - node-hbase Scan not working for more than 1000 records

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, npm, hbase

I want to get records from an HBase table into Node.JS code using node-hbase module which connects to the rest server. But am unable to get the next set of records after the first batch.
So my final count is 1000(which is the batch size). But the actual size is more than 7000.

```
var hbase = require('hbase');
var client = hbase({ host: 'localhost', port: '17001', headers: { 'Connection': 'Keep-Alive' } });

var scanner = client
                .table(tblName)
                .scan({});
var rows = [];
scanner.on('readable', function(){
    var chunk;
    //_results = [];
    while (chunk = scanner.read()) {
        rows.push(chunk);
    }        
    });
scanner.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    });
scanner.on('end', function(){
    console.log(rows.length); 
    })
```

Comment: have you tried using setMaxResultSize(long)?

Comment: @AniruddhaGohad There is no such functionality available for the scanner for this module.

Comment: @AniruddhaGohad Here is the repo of this module. https://github.com/adaltas/node-hbase

Answer (score 0):

On options of scanner: https://hbase.js.org/api/scanner/

```
batch
Number of cells returned on each iteration, internal use, default to "1000".
```

You can set

```
const scanner = client
.table('node_table')
.scan({
  ...
   batch: 100000
  ...
})
```

Or You can check limit memory on your server!